# Error in Google API class in Clojure

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am getting this error while am using calling Google map api in Clojure

```
(defn calculate-distance-matrix
  ""
  [context]
  ;(def nearby-search-fucntion (do-nearby-search property-id context place-type) )
  (let [r (. (. (. (DistanceMatrixApi/newRequest
                     context) origins  (latlng {:lat 44.7415131 :lng 20.4957884}) )
                destinations (latlng {:lat 44.71018809999999 :lng 20.50643759999999}))  await)]
    {:distance (-> r
                   .rows
                   first
                   .elements
                   first
                   .distance
                   .inMeters)
     :duration (-> r
                   .rows
                   first
                   .elements
                   first
                   .distance
                   .inSeconds)})
  )
```

Error message:

```
IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: origins for class com.google.maps.DistanceMatrixApiRequest  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)
```

By the way this is the Latlng function:

```
(defn latlng
  "Accepts a Latitiude and Longitude Key pairs"
  [{:keys [lat lng]}]
  (LatLng. lat lng))
```

Comment: BY the way I added this to project.clj `[com.google.maps/google-maps-services "0.1.17"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`origins` takes a Java varargs which is an array to Clojure. So the call you need to make is probably more like:

```
(. (. (. (DistanceMatrixApi/newRequest context) origins (into-array [(latlng {:lat 44.7415131 :lng 20.4957884})]))
```

where [into-array](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/into-array) takes a collection and returns an array based on the type of the first element of the array (here LatLng).